# Gradle errors when trying to compile with multiple emulators in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, emulation, android-virtual-device

I've been getting this issue for several months now, ever since I updated my Flutter version from 1.12 to 1.17, and it's still happening with Flutter 1.20. Whenever I try compiling to more than 2 simultaneous emulators, Flutter throws different gradle errors, which often change every time I try to compile.

Those are the most common errors: `https://pastebin.com/yDDumfbY`

but I also get a lot of those: `https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/56973`

For some reason, the only thing that fixes this is downgrading Flutter to 1.12.13+hotfix.9, but it's getting harder and harder to work with 1.12 because a lot of packages don't support it anymore and I'm having to use older versions of Firebase, provider, google fonts, etc.

As you can see, I tried getting help in Flutter's repo but I got no luck, so I'm once again trying to get some help with this.

I need multiple emulators because I'm building an online multiplayer game that supports 4 players, so ignoring this bug is not an option for me.

Comment: 1) You should clarify if you are using Android Studio or VSCode. 2) Have you tried different projects (using same code with source control syncing) in order to debug multiple instances of your app as a workaround?

Comment: Just a suggestion but are you using an outdated version of Gradle? I have had some weird issues in the past.

Comment: I'm using Android Studio and yes, I've tried with different projects. I tried gradle 5.6.2, 6.1.1 and 6.3.1 and I also tried build gradle 3.5.0, 3.4.2 and 4.0.1 but none of those worked